# Can I plot a horizontal bar showing the distribution as as well the cutoff value?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to plot a bar like below.

[image]

Here is where I am.

```
attitude <- c('solid_blue', 'leaning_blue', 'toss_up', 'leaning_red', 'solid_red')
n_votes <- c(190, 108, 121, 39, 80)
group <- c(1,1,1,1,1)
df <- rbind(attitude, n_votes, group)
df <- as.data.frame(t(df))

ggplot(data = df) + 
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', mapping = aes (x = group, y = n_votes, fill = attitude)) + coord_flip()
```

where df is like

```
      attitude n_votes group
1   solid_blue     190     1
2 leaning_blue     108     1
3      toss_up     121     1
4  leaning_red      39     1
5    solid_red      80     1
```

I got a plot like this [image]

The n_votes does not seem to accumulate correctly, how can I correct this?

Now I have this [image]

Dan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your main problem is because of the way you constructed your data frame, all the columns in it are character vectors. Look:

```r
class(df$n_votes)
#> [1] "character"
```

It takes less code and gets better results to construct the data frame like this:

```r
attitude <- c('solid_blue', 'leaning_blue', 'toss_up', 'leaning_red', 'solid_red')
n_votes <- c(190, 108, 121, 39, 80)
df <- data.frame(attitude, n_votes, group)
```

Now using your plot code (except noting that `geom_bar(stat = "identity"` is a long-hand way of writing `geom_col(`

```r
ggplot(data = df) + 
  geom_col(aes(x = group, y = n_votes, fill = attitude)) + 
  coord_flip()
```

We get:

[image]

Or, if you want to get closer:

```r
attitude <- c('solid_blue', 'leaning_blue', 'toss_up', 'leaning_red', 'solid_red')
n_votes <- c(190, 108, 121, 39, 80)
df <- data.frame(rev(attitude), rev(n_votes), group)
df$attitude <- factor(rev(attitude), levels = attitude)

ggplot(data = df) + 
  geom_col(aes(x = group, y = n_votes, fill = attitude)) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = rev(c("#2558b1", "#77b3dd", "#cbcbcb", "#f3b0a7", "#d95551")),
                    guide = guide_none()) +
  geom_text(check_overlap = TRUE, label = 298, size = 15, 
            x = 1.8, y = 0, hjust = 0, color = "#2558b1") +
  geom_text(check_overlap = TRUE, label = 119, size = 15, 
            x = 1.8, y = sum(n_votes), hjust = 1, color = "#d95551") +
  geom_text(check_overlap = TRUE, label = "Joe Biden\nDEMOCRAT", 
            size = 5, x = 1.8, y = 60, hjust = 0) +
  geom_text(check_overlap = TRUE, label = "Donald J Trump\nREPUBLICAN", 
            size = 5, x = 1.8, y = sum(n_votes) - 60, hjust = 1) +
  geom_text(check_overlap = TRUE, aes(x = group, y = n_votes, label = n_votes), 
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), size = 5, color = "white") +
  geom_segment(aes(x = 0.55, xend = 1.45, y = sum(n_votes)/2, yend = sum(n_votes)/2),
               linetype = 2) +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_classic() +
  scale_x_discrete(expand = expansion(add = c(0.7, 0.7))) +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "#fdf1e5"),
        plot.margin = margin(50, 10, 50, 10),
        axis.line = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        axis.title = element_blank(),
        axis.text = element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: Instead of coord_flip, you could also use sth like `ggplot(data = df) + 
  geom_col(aes(y = "group", x = n_votes, fill = attitude), orientation = "y")`

Comment: @Tjebo thanks - I know, but I'd started doing the second close reproduction already and can't face swapping all the x's and y's now!

Comment: Jeez! I recreated the df using tibble and it worked. I am about halfway through now.  @AllanCameron Thanks for your help!

Comment: @AllanCameron Hi, Alan I am wondering if there is a way of dropping the redundant area in the panel because the bar in the middle only takes up a small space.